# The club filter in definable preorders

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, model-theory, determinacy

So this is an embarrassing question. Call a preorder $\mathbb{P}$ *good* if it has the following properties:

- Every countable chain in $\mathbb{P}$ has a least upper bound.
- $\mathbb{P}$ is directed (any two elements of $\mathbb{P}$ have an upper bound).
- $\omega_1+1$ does not embed into $\mathbb{P}/\equiv_\mathbb{P}$.
- The domain of $\mathbb{P}$ is a Borel set of reals, and the order relation on $\mathbb{P}$ is a Borel relation on this set.

We can define a club in the context of $\mathbb{P}$ Bullet point (1) above ensures that clubs behave reasonably nicely. Bullet points (2) and (3) prevents $\mathbb{P}$ from "splitting" easily into disjoint stationary sets:

- Suppose (2) fails: let $p$ and $q$ be elements of $\mathbb{P}$ with no upper bound, and consider the sets $X=\{r\in\mathbb{P}: r\ge p\}$ and $Y=\mathbb{P}\setminus X$.
- Suppose (3) fails: then "countable cofinality" and "uncountable cofinality" may define disjoint stationary subsets of $\mathbb{P}$.

Finally, (4) ensures that $\mathbb{P}$ is reasonably nice.

Now, I recall seeing a result to the effect that - under ZF+AD+DC - the club filter on any good $\mathbb{P}$ is in fact an ultrafilter (in the manner of the club filter on $\omega_1$). In particular, I remember this appearing in [a paper of Kueker](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0003484377900109/1-s2.0-0003484377900109-main.pdf?_tid=c64769ae-c405-11e6-bb4e-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1481944156_6c588e73319bded145705c9e2b2b8480). However, looking at that paper, the result doesn't seem to appear, and now I'm not sure it's even true. So:

> In ZF+AD+DC, is the club filter on a good partial order an ultrafilter?

---

Context: I'm thinking about partial orders of countable models of a complete theory, usually ordered by elementary embeddability. I vaguely recall Kueker and others studying such partial orders; references to such would also be welcome.